# I used canvas to create a graphing utility. Is there any way I can also incorporate JButtons, JTextFields etc

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I created a graphing utility using canvas. Currently, information is inputted through the console. However, I want to make the program more presentable by adding inputs via JTextField and JButtons. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Yes, you can add components to the same `JPanel` or to a different `JPanel`. For more help [edit] and post [mre] of what you did, and describe how you want the gui to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JFrameWithCanvas extends JFrame {

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    public JFrameWithCanvas() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pnlToolbar = new JPanel();
        pnlToolbar.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnlToolbar.add(new JButton("foo"));
        getContentPane().add(pnlToolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        canvas.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center it on the screen
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrameWithCanvas().setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't use Canvas, that is an AWT component. For Swing you can use a `JPanel` and override the `paintCompnent(…)` method for custom painting. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.